# Cauchy-Riemann conditions implied by harmonicity and orthogonal gradients?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

If I have two functions $\eta:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\xi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ for which the following relations hold:

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y} \right)^2 &= \left( \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y}\right)^2 \neq 0\,,\\
\frac{\partial^2\xi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\xi}{\partial y^2} &= \frac{\partial^2\eta}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\eta}{\partial y^2} = 0\,,\\
\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y} &= 0\,.
\end{align}$$

Do these conditions imply that these two functions satisfy Cauchy-Riemann conditions?

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y}\,,\\
\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial y} &= -\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}\,.
\end{align}
$$

If so, how to show that? If not, is there some simple condition that would need to be added?

Comment: Note that if $u$ is real harmonic and $v$ is a harmonic conjugate, $-v$ is also orthogonal in the sense above while not changing the equality of the sum of squares of $v_x^2+v_y^2=u_x^2+u_y^2$; the relations above imply that for any $w$ harmonic satisfying them instead of $\pm v$, one has $w_x^2=v_x^2, w_y^2=v_y^2$ and the signs of the solutions match in both equations; since the common zero set of $v_x=v_y=0$ is discrete (zero set of nonconstant entire function), it follows that indeed $w=v+C$ or $w=-v+C$ globally; so one needs an extra condition that separates $v$ from $-v$

Comment: @Conrad I am not sure that I understand. If $v$ is a harmonic conjugate, then already one assumes that the C-R conditions are satisfied because the resultant $f(z) = u + iv$ needs to be holomorphic or not? Also, in the first condition, are you saying that it implies that $u_x^2=v_x^2$ and $u_y^2=v_y^2$?

Comment: The point is that $-v$ (which doesn't satisfy C-R) works too and only those two $v,-v$ work (up to additive constants)

Comment: @Conrad Why does $v$ work or how do the conditions imply that? I do not understand your statement that one needs to have $w_x^2=v_x^2,\, w_y^2=v_y^2$. What I do not see is that if you have the orthogonality condition and Laplace equations for $u$ and $v$ how it implies that $u_x^2 = v_x^2$ and $u_y^2=v_y^2$ (which at least I think is that you are saying).

Comment: posted as an answer to make things clear

Answer (score 0):

A proof for the statement that it $u,w$ are real harmonic and satisfy the two conditions above:

$u_x^2+u_y^2=w_x^2+w_y^2$ (and not identically zero) and $u_xw_x+u_yw_y=0$ then if $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$ we have $w=v+C$ or $w=-v+C$ and conversely those functions work, so one needs an extra condition on $w$ to ensure it is a harmonic conjugate and not a negative of such, for the C-R to hold wr $u,w$.

First, we note that by C-R if $w= \pm v+C$ the identities work.

Then taking $v$ a conjugate of $u$ and substituting the C-R equations in the orthogonality relation, we get $w_xv_y=v_xw_y$ while also $v_x^2+v_y^2=w_x^2+w_y^2$

But now assume at a point $w_y(z) \ne 0$ then it follows that $v_y(z) \ne 0$ (otherwise we must have $v_x(z)=0$ but then $w_x^2(z)+w_y^2(z)=0$ contradicting $w_y(z) \ne 0$) so we get at $z$:

$w_x^2/w_y^2=v_x^2/v_y^2$ or adding $1$ to each side $(w_x^2+w_y^2)/w_y^2=(v_x^2+v_y^2)/v_y^2$ and since the numerators are equal and non zero, we get $w_y^2(z)=v_y^2(z)$ so $w_y = \pm v_y$

If $w_y(z)=0$ then automatically $v_y(z)=0$ (since if it would not, then $w_x(z)=0$ and then the sum of squares is zero etc) so the equality holds everywhere.

By the same reasoning $w_x= \pm v_x$ everywhere and of course, if we are at a non-zero value of both $v_x, v_y$ the signs must coincide which means that $w_y=v_y$ or $w_y=-v_y$ on any connected component of the complement of $v_x=0$ (set being same with $w_x=0$ by the above, while the common zeroes of $v_x,v_y$ are discrete of course as they are zeroes of a non-constant analytic function $(u+iv)'$); but now $w_y+v_y$ is a real harmonic function and same with $w_y-v_y$ so if either is zero on any open set, it is zero in the plane, hence we must have the same sign everywhere and then the same holds for $w_x,v_x$ and we are done as we get that either $w=v+C$ or $w=-v+C$